# Specified cast is not valid when using casting

Tags: c#, linq, casting, double, datarow

I'm getting the following error when trying to get the **sum in this Linq query**:

> InvalidCastException was unhandled. Specified cast is not valid.

I used the DataType property to triple check is that column is in fact a Double, and it is.

```
foreach (DataColumn item in _dttMasterViewTransaction.Columns)
{
    if (item.ColumnName == "Dr")
    {
        //Outputs: System.Double!
        MessageBox.Show(item.DataType.ToString());
    }
}

var datos = _dttMasterViewTransaction.AsEnumerable().Where(r => (int)r["Entity"] == FundsID).Select(r => new EntityJESummary()
{
    JEId = (int)r["JE ID"],
    JEGroupingId = (int)r["JE Group"],
    PartnershipId = (int)r["Entity"],
    BookingDate = Convert.ToDateTime(r["GL Date"]),
    EffectiveDate = Convert.ToDateTime(r["Effective Date"]),
    Allocated = Convert.ToBoolean(r["Allocated"]),
    JEEstate = (int)r["JE State"],
    JEComments = r["JE Comments"].ToString(),

    Debit = _dttMasterViewTransaction.AsEnumerable().Where(s => (int)r["Entity"] == FundsID).Sum(s => (double)s["Dr"]),
    Credit = _dttMasterViewTransaction.AsEnumerable().Where(s => (int)r["Entity"] == FundsID).Sum(s => (double)s["CR"])

}).First();
```

Any suggestions on why this could occur?

Comment: Are you attempting to cast strings to `int`s by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are any of the entries null for that field?  or are there some that are not doubles?

we'd need to see more data to get a better answer...

Comment: By the way, in case anyone falls into the same trouble. I used: `.Sum(s => (s["Dr"] == DBNull.Value) ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(s["Dr"]))`

Comment: that DBNull thing bites **everyone** at least once.  i'm not sure why they chose to have a special sentinal value for null instead of just using null..

Answer (score 0):

If the values can be either null or an empty string, try this:

```
Debit = _dttMasterViewTransaction.AsEnumerable().Where(s => (int)r["Entity"] == FundsID).Sum(s => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s["Dr"]) ? 0d : (double)s["Dr"])),
Credit = _dttMasterViewTransaction.AsEnumerable().Where(s => (int)r["Entity"] == FundsID).Sum(s => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s["CR"]) ? 0d : (double)s["CR"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Nullable form of Sum.

```
Debit = _dttMasterViewTransaction.AsEnumerable().Where(s => (int)r["Entity"] == 
FundsID).Sum(s => (double?)s["Dr"]),     
Credit = _dttMasterViewTransaction.AsEnumerable().Where(s => (int)r["Entity"] == 
FundsID).Sum(s => (double?)s["CR"])
```

Check this link for more details:

http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/07/15/applying-aggregates-to-empty-collections-causes-exception-in-linq-to-sql.aspx